# Change URL for IIS Express?

Tags: iis-express

I want IIS Express to server a folder. In the output I get:

```
Successfully registered URL "http://localhost:8080/" for site "Development Web Site" application "/"
```

I would like to change the URL. The closest I have found is the following in applicationhost.config:

```
    <site name="Development Web Site" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
        <application path="/">
            <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%IIS_BIN%\AppServer\empty_wwwroot" />
        </application>
        <bindings>
            <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":8080:localhost" />
        </bindings>
    </site>
```

If I change localhost to something like "localhost.test.com" I still see a message that the URL being registered is "localhost". Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example from Microsoft for the binding.

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="127.0.0.1:8080:localhost.test.com" />
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/sitedefaults/bindings/binding

If you are planning to leave it running, enable the full featured IIS. This is a Windows 10 example.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181052(v=vs.80).aspx

Lastly, if you want to change urls, you can use the URL rewrite feature:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2016/08/25/setup-iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-real-world-apps/

If you are trying to go to localhost.test.com, your DNS is likely going to point you to test.com and not stay within your server, unless you update your host file, which would be weird, so I don’t recommend doing that.

Comment: I am trying to go to localhost.test.com. I have added localhost.test.com to my etc/hosts file and it essentially resolves to 127.0.0.1. I need to specifically bind to localhost.test.com to satisfy the needs of my single-signon.

Comment: I changed the config file to be
<bindings>
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="localhost.test.com:8080:" />
</bindings>
And I still get 
. . . .
Copied template config file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS 
Starting IIS Express ...
Successfully registered URL "http://localhost:8080/" for site "Development Web Site" application "/"
Registration completed
IIS Express is running.

Comment: Updated binding in my comment

Comment: Assumes you want port 8080

Comment: I changed applicationhost.config to
`<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="127.0.0.1:8080:localhost.test.com" />`
and I still get `Successfully registered URL "http://localhost:8080/" for site "Development Web Site" application "/"`